C# stored procedure returns all rows in the table for null values
I have method GetUserPermissions which returns user permission rows from the database using a stored procedure based on UserId which is passed in as a parameter. The issue is that it's returning all rows if null is passed as parameter.

public static List<UserPermission> GetUserPermissions(UserPermissionArgs userPermissionArgs)
{
     var permissions = helper.GetModelFromDB<UserPermission>("GetUserPermissions", GetNonNullAttributes(userPermissionArgs).ToArray()).ToList();

     permissions = permissions.GroupBy(d => d.PermissionId).Select(x => x.First()).ToList();

     // Add available permissions that user does not have to list of permissions
     var allPermissions = GetPermission(new PermissionArgs() { });

     foreach (var permission in allPermissions)
     {
         if (permissions.All(p => p.PermissionId != permission.Id))
         {
             permissions.Add(new UserPermission() { PermissionId = permission.Id, State = false });
         }
     }

     Parallel.ForEach(permissions, permission => permission.Permission = GetPermission(new PermissionArgs()
     { PermissionId = permission.PermissionId }).Single());

     return permissions.ToList();
}

private static IEnumerable<SqlParameter> GetNonNullAttributes(object args, bool checkStringsEmpty = true)
{
    PropertyInfo[] properties = args.GetType().GetProperties();
    List<SqlParameter> parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();

    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {
        object[] attributes = property.GetCustomAttributes(true);

        foreach (var attribute in attributes.Where(attribute => attribute.GetType() == typeof(SpParameter)).Where(attribute => property.GetValue(args) != null))
        {
            if (checkStringsEmpty && property.GetType() == typeof(string))
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)property.GetValue(args)))
                {
                    //If string is empty, don't add it as a parameter
                    continue;
                }
            }

            SpParameter param = (SpParameter)attribute;
            parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(param.Name, property.GetValue(args)));
        }
    }

    return parameters;
}


What is the expected behavior if you pass in null ? What do you want to get back in this case?

You forgot to show us the definition of the stored proc.

Parallel.ForEach(permissions, permission => permission.Permission = GetPermission(new PermissionArgs()      { PermissionId = permission.PermissionId }).Single()); As a side issue - this is a terrible way to abuse a database. Databases are great at returning lots of data. Why ask for data a row at a time (in parallel - thus wasting threads and introducing considerable synchronisation overhead) rather than ask for all of them at once?

The issue stems from the GetNonNullAttributes method, which currently filters out any properties where the value is null. This means that if UserId is null, it won't be included in the list of SQL parameters, and the stored procedure will execute without any parameters—hence returning all rows.
You need to include parameters even if their values are null. Modify the method to remove the check that filters out null values like this:
foreach (var attribute in attributes
    .Where(attribute => attribute.GetType() == typeof(SpParameter)))
{
    // ...
}

